# How to send url encoded data using post method in java

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send url encoded data using HttpURLConnection method in java. Client shared the below string from Soap UI tester as a sample request:

http://www.clienturl.com/payment?username=bk&password=bk&customerid=100039085&amountcredit=100&operationdate=2018-07-17&event=9977773&reference=2323900&account=00000000&valuedate=2018-07-17&terminal=00010

I've tried all combinations of sending data using java. Am getting response code as 200, but the response is showing that missing mandatory parameters in the request. Please help if there are any error in my code, in writing the request.

```
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    String EndPointURL = url;
    String requestXML = "username=bk&password=bk&customerid=78233209438&amountcredit=100&operationdate=2018-07-17&event=9977773&reference=13903232&account=000000&valuedate=2018-07-17&terminal=00010";
    String encodedData = URLEncoder.encode(requestXML, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("Encoded data: " + encodedData);

    URL localURL = new URL(EndPointURL);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) localURL.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(encodedData.length()));
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Okhttp3, use this code :

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "string-that-you-need-to-pass-in-body");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("url-string")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

For Unirest :

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("url-string")
  .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .body("string-that-you-need-to-pass-in-body")
  .asString();
```

Comment: Believe, instead of body, one would need to use field method as in field("username", "username")
    .field("password", "password")